# Collision Detection crowd netlogo

Tags: netlogo, collision

This is what I have.  I need turtles to move from circle formation and 
        move to another spot while preventing collisions and getting into a 
        circle again.

```
    ;;creates circle of people
    turtles-own [collides?]
    to setup
      clear-all

      setup-circle
      reset-ticks
    end
   to setup-circle
     create-ordered-turtles crowd-size [
       set shape "person" fd 10 rt 90]
   end
   to go
     ask turtles [
     fd .1 
     ]

     tick
   end
```

Comment: Please share more context. Which kind of programming language is that? And what exactly is not working yet?

Comment: It is Netlogo.  A simulation environment.  I am new to it.  I would like them to move towards the center of the circle and cross to the other side to recreate the same circle.  Currently they go everywhere.

Comment: Have a look at GasLab in the models library for some code you might want about detecting overlaps. You need to break down your objectives into smaller ones and do one at a time. Some of these might be detect potential collision, avoid collision, choose target, move toward target... For example, if a turtle avoids a collision, does it then want to keep trying to get to where it was heading to or does it pick a new place to try and get to?

Comment: You should also look up `face` in the NetLogo dictionary and make sure you understand about `heading` - the reason they go in all directions is because you asked them to move forward (with whatever heading they have). Once you've picked the first bit to work on, come back with a more specific question when you get stuck on implementing that bit.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  We figured it would be too difficult for anyone on these boards to answer...

Comment: What do you think is too difficult? These boards have many people able to answer NetLogo questions, including several NetLogo developers. But you haven't asked a specific question yet.